# What is the upper limit for a charge-pump voltage booster?

Tags: high-voltage, charge-pump

What is the highest voltage achieved with a voltage pump? Can it boost into the kV range, around 5-10kV?

Comment: What circuit topology are you considering and what input supply voltage and load current are you also considering? I've used cockroft-walton multipliers to deliver 55 kV.

Comment: @Andyaka I am not really thinking of making anything specifically right now, I was just curious as these are kinda cool, I might consider them for a small high voltage capacitor bank charger.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When stacked indeed it can go well into the kV range using a charge-pump voltage booster. In fact it is a very common approach.

Here is an image of such a high-voltage setup.

[image]

The proper name for this circuit is a "Cockcroft–Walton generator". Here is the wikipedia on that circuit:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cockcroft%E2%80%93Walton_generator

Here is a video of a 75KV version:

https://youtu.be/3_rdzmfdlpo

There have been designs that go even much higher than that. Here is a picture of a 3MV (3000KV) version:

[image]

As for the maximum voltage you can achieve, there is no real limit in theory other than arcing, which is one reason these designs are useful for extremely high voltages. Each capacitor in the stack is exposed to the same relative voltage across it since it is only connected between each stage, as are the diodes. so you can stack as many as you like without any real limit so long as you keep the high voltage leads far enough away from anything it could arc to.

However in practice there is a practical limit. As the voltage increases even if this is sitting out in the middle of free space the increased voltage is going to mean increased leakage, and that means there is going to be some current flowing. The higher the voltage the more current flows. So at a certain point the thing will leak and the capacitors wont fully charge anymore. so you'd have to use bigger and bigger components until it becomes impractical.

This problem is exaggerated by the fact that the more stages you have in the circuit the higher the impedance (increasing exponentially) and the less current it can deliver before the voltage will start to drop. In practice even with very few stages it can't deliver very much current at all. This is why even a small leakage current can quickly limit the circuits effectiveness.

Comment: There's another limiting factor.  The impedance of the whole thing goes up as the cube of the number of stages.  $$ E_{out} = 2nE_{pk} - \frac {I_{load}}{2 \pi fC} (4n^3 + 3n^2 - n) - 2nV_{f}$$

Comment: A Cockcroft-Walton voltage multiplier is a tradeoff between the size (capacitance) of the capacitors, the number of stages, the operating frequency, and the starting voltage.  Practically, most designs top out at 8 or 9 stages because you can't get any useful current from them with that number of stages.

Comment: The circuit is sometimes referred to as a diode ladder. If you want to draw even a small current, the voltage achievable begins to drop sharply.

Comment: I will mention some of these details, thank you.

Comment: @JRE very interesting, I'd love to see the analysis that led to that loaded output voltage formula. Thanks

Comment: @carloc:  I found it on a somewhat flaky site, [then verified it experimentally.](https://josepheoff.github.io/posts/diode-capacitors-volts-pt7)  I tried figuring it out myself, but getting from raw numbers to that equation would have taken more experimenting and number crunching than I wanted to do.

Comment: Thank you much @JRE

Comment: @JRE I was sure I once read something about it, Got it now https://www.dropbox.com/s/jnvqytcu7je2y2v/CW.pdf?dl=0 and share with you. Formula (2.9) is what your one resembles

Comment: @carloc:  Thanks.  I'll read through that and see how they worked it out.  Equation 2.9 is the interesting bit  that matches the equation I found.